# How to calculate confidence interval from multiple data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, computer-vision, confidence-interval

I am sampling 159 videos, trying to do experiments and see how much sample rate affects some evaluation score.

I got a pretty messy picture [image]

Each line is a single video. Y axis is the evaluation score, X axis is number of frames I skip (in other words, sample rate).

So the picture tells me it is pretty stable the sample rate is 1, 3, 5, 8, and 10. But I want to have a confidence interval, say, "97.5% confident the score is stable for these sample rates". Here 97.5% is fake. I know how to get mean/variance for a single video, and how to get a real confidence value? Can someone point me the resource or teach me the way to do it? I'm using python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you assume normal distribution, then `mean +- 1.96 * standard deviation` for a 95 % confidence interval.

Comment: That's incorrect. Assuming an underlying normal distribution, the 95% CI is given by the `mean ± 1.96 * se`, where the standard error (of the mean) is `se = sd / sqrt(n)`. Note the critical difference between "standard error" and "standard deviation"!